# How to filter columns in awk?

Tags: unix, compiler-construction, awk

I was wondering how to filter the following lines in AWK:

```
DSL - 

  1. Digital Simulation Language.  Extensions to FORTRAN to simulate analog
computer functions.  "DSL/90 - A Digital Simulation Program for Continuous
System Modelling", Proc SJCC 28, AFIPS (Spring 1966).  Version: DSL/90 for
the IBM 7090.  Sammet 1969, p.632.

FLIP - 

  1. Early assembly language on G-15.  Listed in CACM 2(5):16 (May 1959).

  2. "FLIP User's Manual", G. Kahn, TR 5, INRIA 1981.

  3. Formal LIst Processor.  Early language for pattern-matching on LISP
structures.  Similar to CONVERT.  "FLIP, A Format List Processor", W.
Teitelman, Memo MAC-M-263, MIT 1966.
```

So I can get something like this:

```
DSL

FLIP
```

I am using the following sentences in AWK:

```
BEGIN { RS = "\n\n\n" ;  FS = " - " } 

{ print $1 }
```

But what I get is just this:

```
DSL
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you need X (3?) number of blank lines after your 2nd entry. Good luck.

Comment: what do you mean @shellter ?

Comment: your RS is set to `\n\n\n` and your sample data doesn't look to have blank lines at the end of the file, so that "record" won't be processed. Good luck.

Comment: Oh I got it! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@JonathanLeffler gave you a good awk answer to your specific question but if you're going to be working on files with that format a lot, you may want to consider reformatting them to have records separated by newlines with each list item on a single line, e.g.:

```
$ cat file
DSL -

  1. Digital Simulation Language.  Extensions to FORTRAN to simulate analog
computer functions.  "DSL/90 - A Digital Simulation Program for Continuous
System Modelling", Proc SJCC 28, AFIPS (Spring 1966).  Version: DSL/90 for
the IBM 7090.  Sammet 1969, p.632.

FLIP -

  1. Early assembly language on G-15.  Listed in CACM 2(5):16 (May 1959).

  2. "FLIP User's Manual", G. Kahn, TR 5, INRIA 1981.

  3. Formal LIst Processor.  Early language for pattern-matching on LISP
structures.  Similar to CONVERT.  "FLIP, A Format List Processor", W.
Teitelman, Memo MAC-M-263, MIT 1966.

$ awk '!/^[[:space:]]*$/{printf "%s%s", (NF==2 && /-[[:space:]]*$/ ? rs rs : (/^ +[[:digit:]]+\./ ? rs : "")), $0; rs="\n"} END{print ""}' file
DSL -
  1. Digital Simulation Language.  Extensions to FORTRAN to simulate analogcomputer functions.  "DSL/90 - A Digital Simulation Program for ContinuousSystem Modelling", Proc SJCC 28, AFIPS (Spring 1966).  Version: DSL/90 forthe IBM 7090.  Sammet 1969, p.632.

FLIP -
  1. Early assembly language on G-15.  Listed in CACM 2(5):16 (May 1959).
  2. "FLIP User's Manual", G. Kahn, TR 5, INRIA 1981.
  3. Formal LIst Processor.  Early language for pattern-matching on LISPstructures.  Similar to CONVERT.  "FLIP, A Format List Processor", W.Teitelman, Memo MAC-M-263, MIT 1966.
```

That way you can process the output easily to print or do whatever else you want, e.g.

1) to print every header line plus first bullet item:

```
$ awk '...' file | awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"} {print $1,$2}'
DSL -
  1. Digital Simulation Language.  Extensions to FORTRAN to simulate analogcomputer functions.  "DSL/90 - A Digital Simulation Program for ContinuousSystem Modelling", Proc SJCC 28, AFIPS (Spring 1966).  Version: DSL/90 forthe IBM 7090.  Sammet 1969, p.632.

FLIP -
  1. Early assembly language on G-15.  Listed in CACM 2(5):16 (May 1959).
```

2) to print the header line plus the second bullet item of just the "FLIP" record:

```
$ awk '...' file | awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; ORS="\n\n"; FS=OFS="\n"} /^FLIP -/{print $1,$3}'
FLIP -
  2. "FLIP User's Manual", G. Kahn, TR 5, INRIA 1981.
```

3) to print the header line plus a count of the bullet items for that header:

```
$ awk '...' file | awk 'BEGIN{RS=""; FS=OFS="\n"} {print $1 NF-1}'
DSL - 1
FLIP - 3
```

etc., etc.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Ed Morton. Although, I have had a new problem cause what I have to filter is a file containing more than 2000 different programming languages with different formats, not just the ones from this post. Thanks again anyway

Comment: Yes, you will find that given input that's a different format from what you posted, the script that parses the format of input you posted will not work. If you;d like help parsing your real input, post a new question with examples of that.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the format is constant (no spaces in first entry):

```
if ($2=="-"){print $1}
```

Edit: but if you had an entry like:

```
Objective C -
...
```

You would need something like:

```
if ($NF=="-"){$NF="";print}
```

awk is really good at parsing flat files that are in a *predictable* format.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you're looking for a line with two words only on it, and the second word is `-`.  If so, then you could write:

```
awk 'NF == 2 && $2 == "-" { print $1 }'
```

You could further qualify it to insist that `$1` starts at the beginning of the line (no leading blanks):

```
awk '$0 !~ /^ / && NF == 2 && $2 == "-" { print $1 }'
```

Both these produce lines containing just `DSL` and `FLIP` on the given data.

Comment: I have created an awk file with the following: BEGIN{$0 !~ /^ / && NF == 2 && $2 == "-"} { print $1 } and it does not do what I expected to. Thanks anyway @Jonathan Leffler

Answer (score 0):

If all the lines you want to skip start with a space this will work:

```
awk -F"-" '{if (substr($1,1,1)!=" ")print $1}'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately, when your script is run against the example data, it produces 12 lines of output, not 2.  It eliminates those lines that start with a blank.  (Granted, if the list items were each on a single long line instead of several shorter ones, it would work better, but it would still print the empty lines too.)

Comment: it could also be written as just `awk -F"-" '$0!~/^ /{print $1}'`, no need for substr().

Comment: It's not working for me @Ed Morton. It skips and prints lines that I do not need. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @MikePérez - it's not possible for `$0!~/^ /` and `substr($1,1,1)!=" "` to produce different results given an FS of "-". You must have copy/pasted wrong or something.

Answer (score 0):

a short **grep** line can do it for you:

```
grep -Po '.*(?= -\s*$)' file
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Although I need it in AWK